# Take backup of AWS configuration across all services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Having spent a couple of days setting up and configuring a new AWS account I would like to grab an export of the account configuration across all services. I've Googled around for existing scripts, etc, but have yet to find anything that would automate this process.

Primarily this would be as a backup incase the account was corrupted in some way (including user error!) but this would also be useful to document the system.

From an account administration perspective, there are various parts of the AWS console that don't display friendly names for various resources. Being able to cross reference against offline documentation would simplify these scenarios. For example, friendly names for vpc's and subnets aren't always displayed when configuring resources to use them.

Lastly I would like to be able to use this to spot suspicious changes to the configuration as part of intrusion detection. For example, looking out for security group changes to protected resources.

To clarify, I am looking to backup the *configuration* of AWS resources, not the actual resources themselves. Resource backups (e.g. EC2 instances) is already covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest i've seen to that is [CloudFormer](http://aws.amazon.com/developertools/6460180344805680).

That would create a CloudFormation template from your account's resources. Mind that this template would be only a starting point, not meant to be reproducible out-of-the-box. For example, it won't log into your instances or anything like that.

As for the intrusion detection part, see [CloudTrail](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/)

Comment: Thanks Julio - for some reason I have never come across CloudFormer and that does indeed look as close as I am going to get. Have had a play with it and it looks promising.

Comment: Looks like ClkoudFormer is no longer available, any other solutions?

Comment: If all you need is configuration, just enable AWS Config: https://aws.amazon.com/config/

Answer (score 4):

Check out AWS Config: https://aws.amazon.com/config/

AWS Config records the configuration of AWS resources automatically, allowing you to query and react to configuration changes. As AWS Config stores data on S3, that is probably enough backup, but you can also sync the bucket elsewhere for paranoid redundancy.

Comment: That URL doesn't work anymore.